# How to get the week number for day irrespective of the calendar week number in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to get the week number for the day irrespective of the calendar week in Python?

Iam looking for the column "nth_week_number" .In the below table "2/5/2018" will fall in the 2nd week of the Feb 2018 but It was a 1st Monday of that Month. Someone please help to resolve this in Python.
Iam using Pythno 3.7.

```
Date        | Weekday   | week _of_the_month | nth_week_number |
|-----------|-----------|--------------------|-----------------|
| 2/1/2018  | Thursday  | 1                  | 1st Thrusday    |
| 2/2/2018  | Friday    | 1                  | 1st Friday      |
| 2/3/2018  | Saturday  | 1                  | 1st Saturday    |
| 2/4/2018  | Sunday    | 2                  | 1st Sunday      |
| 2/5/2018  | Monday    | 2                  | 1st Monday      |
| 2/6/2018  | Tuesday   | 2                  | 1st Tuesday     |
| 2/7/2018  | Wednesday | 2                  | 1st Wednesday   |
| 2/8/2018  | Thursday  | 2                  | 2nd Thrusday    |
| 2/9/2018  | Friday    | 2                  | 2nd Friday      |
| 2/10/2018 | Saturday  | 2                  | 2nd Saturday    |
| 2/11/2018 | Sunday    | 3                  | 2nd Sunday      |
| 2/12/2018 | Monday    | 3                  | 2nd Monday      |
| 2/13/2018 | Tuesday   | 3                  | 2nd Tuesday     |
```

Comment: Please provide more descriptions. The problem statement is not very clear.

Comment: Do you just want the day of the month divided by 7?

Comment: I *think* the question is asking how to calculate for a given date that that date is the *n*th *day-name* of the month it falls in, i.e. the second Monday in February, etc. Please edit it to make this clearer. Please show some code you've written to try something out, and describe what's wrong with what you've got so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below snippet will give you the week number and day

```
        import datetime
        import calendar
        day_of_month = datetime.datetime(2018,2,11).day
        week_number = (day_of_month - 1) // 7 + 1
        print(week_number, datetime.datetime(2018,2,11).strftime("%A"))
```

Comment: Above code is not working when i tried to get the same result by adding new coumn in Dataframe. I used below code, 

df['formatted_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['new_date'])
df['day_of_year'] = df.formatted_date.apply(lambda x: x.dayofyear)
df['week_of_year'] = df.formatted_date.apply(lambda x: x.weekofyear)
df['week_of_month']= (df['week_of_year'] - 1) // 7 + 1

Issue: The above code is not creating Weeknumber for all the day.

Comment: In excel by using below function we can get the same result,
=(ROUNDUP(DAY(A1)/7;0)&". "&TEXT(A1;"dddd"))

Comment: Also Iam looking for the Column :"week _of_the_month" to generate in dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

```
data = {'date_x': ['2018-02-13']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['date_x'])
df['formatted_date'] = pd.to_datetime('2018-02-13')
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date_x'])
df['first_day_aux']=pd.to_datetime(df['date_x'][0][:8]+'01') 
df['day']=df['date'].dt.day 
df['adjusted_dom']=df['day']+df['first_day_aux'].dt.dayofweek
df['year'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['formatted_date']).year
df['month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['formatted_date']).month
df['day'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['formatted_date']).day
df['weekday'] = datetime.datetime(df['year'],df['month'],df['day']).strftime("%A")
df['day_of_month'] = datetime.datetime(df['year'],df['month'],df['day']).day
df['week']=np.int_(np.ceil(df['adjusted_dom']/7.0))
df['week number'] = (df['day_of_month'] - 1 ) // 7 + 1
print(df)
```